# How to find a young project in GitHub?

Tags: github, open-source, project

I want to find some newly-created Github projects which will be easy to understand and contribute to. But in GitHub there's only a "explore" function that lists the most popular projects. How do I find the projects that are not so popular or mature? Do I need to write a program to query their developer API for this information, or is there an easier way to find newly-created projects on Github? Thanks.

Comment: Off-topic since this has nothing to do with programming and more on how to use search. This is the same as if you were asking how to filter Google News search.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that. Know more about how to use stackoverflow now.

Comment: He didn't actually know it had to do with search until I answered it that way, below! He may have thought he needed to access their API. I will re-word the question to help clarify that.

Comment: Megan, Thank you for helping me edit the question. After checking with help center of StackOverflow on "What topic can I ask here", I think this question might be categorized as "practical, answerable problems that are unique to software development". With answers to this question, I and other people who are not familiar with GitHub can take use of it better so as to start open-source software development. At last, among all the Stack Exchange sites (Super User, Server Fault etc.) StackOverflow is the place most fit this question. Have a good day!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

On their search details page github lists some ways to find this information:

https://help.github.com/articles/searching-repositories

> You can filter repositories based on times of creation, or when they
>   were last updated. For repository creation, you can use the created
>   qualifier;

Example:

```
ruby created:>2014-01-01
    Matches repositories with the word "ruby" that were created after Jan 1, 2014
```

Good luck, and I'm glad you are wanting to contribute to an open source project!

Comment: Thank you Megan, the searching syntaxes from this page are pretty helpful!

Comment: @Megan https://github.com/search/advanced Add this to answer. We can directly search from here.